# "This question is opinion-based." - but is it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

This question ([What is the practical difference between a tibble, data.frame, and data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64561644/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-a-tibble-data-frame-and-data-table)) which asks the question of the practical difference between the three widely used methods to store and process data in R, has been closed as "opinion based".

What is the best action to take if I disagree with this decision?
Is it opinion based, or open to interpretation that way?

Comment: The *should not* is a problematic phrase, since it's asking for judgement, not just comparison. The question is also somewhat broad. The question is salvageable, but needs some editing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @yivi. While I can agree that the question may be too broad, it is commonly asked and as such a resource should be available on. As for being opinion based, I fail to see how.

Comment: It's too broad by miles, (or kilometres in normal locations).  If narrowed, eg. by specifying a particular requirement and constraints, it could be opinion-based.  Either way, it's a bad question:(

Comment: Generally asking for list of differences is too broad and reopening questions to close for different reason is not an advised course of actions. (Note that it may be not too broad for particular framework or language- can’t judge R myself)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I disagree with this assessment.  There's reasons to ask about technical differences and situational uses for a given data type, and those can be practical and answerable questions without any subjectivity in it.

I would probably elect to have this reopened.  An expert in R can answer this with no ambiguity.

Comment: Agreed *in general*, but I think this particular question, as currently worded, seems a bit too broad. I'm not taking any action, though, because I don't have any expertise in R, certainly not enough to override the community.